# Does the Catholic Church teach that the bread and wine are transubstantiated in Protestant churches?

Tags: catholicism, communion, transubstantiation, wine

According to the Catholic Church, do the bread and wine literally become the body and blood of Christ when a Protestant church observes the Lord's Supper? What if the church uses grape juice that does not meet the Catholic requirements for mustum?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the requirements for the wine to be fermented (which is a requirement, it cannot be grape juice), if a Protestant congregation observes the Lord's Supper, it is not the Body and Blood, Soul and Divinity of Christ.

Most Protestants don't believe in the Real Presence of Jesus in the Eucharist (if they did, they'd probably want to be Catholic) and even those that do (Anglicans and some Lutherans, maybe others) broke off with Rome in a split that (unlike the Orthodox Schism in 1052) rendered their ministers unable to say Mass in any capacity.

Only a validly ordained priest who has been given the authority to do so by his bishop can celebrate the Mass and only during the Mass does the bread and wine become the Body, Blood, Soul and Divinity of Jesus.

> The minister who is able to confect the sacrament of the Eucharist in the person of Christ is a validly ordained priest alone.

Another thing I've heard lately is that the term "transubstantiation" is really taken a bit to far or literally or people get hung up on it.  It's a term to describe and distinguish the unique event, it's not the Thing Itself.

It's really only useful in distinguishing it from the Lutheran belief in consubstantiation, which means that they believe Jesus's presence is with the host at communion and departs thereafter.

That's why we Catholics can literally worship Jesus in the Eucharist and Protestants might consider that idolatrous. But even C.S. Lewis, the famous Anglican, wrote in the Weight of Glory, that if we could see each other's glory, we'd be strongly tempted to worship one another - and that is the next best thing to worshiping Jesus in the Holy Sacrament on the altar.

---

On the other hand, and not to confuse the point, but in my experience (and I cannot attest to whether this is licit or not) I've known Catholic priests to say Mass in a Protestant church building in a pinch, like if a Catholic Church is being renovated or rebuilt and the congregation needs a temporary home.  It's likely a better spot for an oratory, being ostensibly a quiet and reverent area reserved for prayer to Jesus, than a gym, strip mall or other public area.

Comment: I think the Lutheran concept of consubstantiation is that the consecrated host is the body of Christ and it is also still bread. (I'm Catholic, but I was given this explanation by a Lutheran minister --- Wisconsin Synod, in case that matters.)

Comment: Most Protestants **DO** believe in the Real Presence, *not* in the Eucharist but in the heart of each partaker (by faith), although Lutherans, who use the formula "present wholly and entirely, in his body and blood, under the signs of bread and wine", are closer to Catholics.  About saying Mass outside a Catholic building containing a consecrated altar, I have seen pictures of a Catholic priest celebrating mass at the summit of a mountain at the end of a hiking trail, which is quite cool.

Comment: "rendered their ministers unable to say Mass in any capacity" No. Only groups that lack valid orders lack valid Eucharist. Orthodox Eucharist is valid (and can be received by Catholics in some circumstances). It lacks licitness. "who has been given the authority to do so by his bishop can celebrate the Mass" Depending on how you mean "can", the bishop's permission only affects licitness not validity.

Comment: Technically, the requirement for fermentation is not absolute, since mustus (young wine) can be substituted in certain cases.

Among Protestants, Wesleyans, Anglicans, and Lutherans hold to a real presence of some sort as a denominational distinctive (though this is not universal among American Wesleyans in my experience). Wesleyans generally do not attempt to explain the presence, Anglicans are similar, and Lutherans hold to consubstantiation.

I also have concerns with regards to the position on the validity of the sacrament, but that's a matter where everyone's stances are known.